# Python: How to write a list created from for loop into a text file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, text

Using a dictionary to sort data, I created a list of zip codes and their population. I then used a for loop to go through each key in my dictionary to find matching zip codes and add their population if there were duplicate values (some ZIPs appeared multiple times). I now need to take my long list that was created in a for loop and put it into a text file. My issue is when I go to write the list back into a file it only picks up my last 2 values. My code works error free, but is not populating my full list in a text file. Below is a preview of my code to date that capture my zip codes and populations once totaled.

```
for k in dict.keys():
    zip = (k)
    total_pop = int(dict[k]['pop']
    zip_list = [zip, str(total_pop)]
    new_zip_list = ",".join(zip_list)

    with open("test_file.txt", "w") as output:
       for row in new_zip_list:
           output.write(str(row)+"\n")
```

I was told you can't write a list into a text file, so the new_zip_list line was created to turn my list into a strings. Not sure if that is correct though?

Comment: Did you mean to have the ‘with open()’ as the first line?

Comment: I was not sure where to put the "with open()" line honestly. It appears that when I try to write the list into a file it is not picking up every element in the for loop that I created.

Comment: btw Don't use built-ins like `dict` and `zip` as your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to lie in this code: `open("test_file.txt", "w") as output:`.

You're writing to the file instead of appending to it, so instead of adding to the text file, you are essentially deleting its contents and overwriting what was there

So I suggest changing it to:
`open("test_file.txt", "a") as output:`

If you know that this file doesn't exist already and you want to access it only once you could move `open("test_file.txt", "w") as output:` to before the first for loop, and this will create the file and let you write to it.

Comment: Ahh, that works better but I still have an issue. The code is appending or essentially adding each individual element to a new line. So instead of printing the first zip code as "513" the 5, 1, and 3 all appear on a new line in the file, which I dont want!

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `output.write(new_zip_list)` instead of `for row in new_zip_list`?

Comment: Im a beginner, so believe me, I am confused :(. I have made the updates you suggested so my "with open" line is now above the for loop for my dictionary. I then constructed the new list based on your comment. Now when I print the list it looks good until it hits the line. For some reason the list populated but last value is now printed over and over again on top of the corrected list. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @jackosumtrades I have done this and it is semi-working. When I go to write the list back into the file it is giving me each object on a single line. However, I want a single zip code and its population to be on the same line, then have a new line for the next zip/pop. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1) Move the `with` line to the top, outside the loop. This will fix the problem that @jackosumtrades pointed out.

2) Change the way you construct `new_zip_list`. Right now, it's a string. When you iterate over a string with a `for` loop, it gives you one character at a time. Here's one way to do it:

```
new_zip_list = [] # initialize

for k in dict.keys():
    new_zip_list.append(zip_list)

with open("test_file.txt", "w") as output:
    # write your output here
```

As a sidenote, your code is pretty confusing. First, you're using `zip` as a variable, overriding the name of a built-in function. Second, the variables `zip_list` and `new_zip_list` don't really tell you what those variables do or mean (also, as you have it now, only one of them is an actual list). Finally, you make `total_pop` an int, and then turn around and convert it to a string.

Comment: **UPDATE** I got it figured out. Thank you everyone for your help. Please do not spend any more time on this!